# Failed to resolve: firebase-messaging-15.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

**This is my build gradle (App)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0:15.0.0'
```

}

**In the build gradle (Project)**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
}
}



allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}
}
```

Here is the error

*Failed to resolve: firebase-messaging-15.0.0*

The Firebase assistant show that **Dependencies set up correctly**, but Sycn fail. Please help me.

Answer (score 5):

Try changing the version of firebase messaging to 17.3.2 like

> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0:15.0.0'
```

into this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'
```

`com.google.firebase` is the group id

`firebase-messaging` is the artifact id

`17.3.2` is the version

Check the versions here:

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Answer (score 0):

Either use `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'` or `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'`

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation of [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries) you can downloading with

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0:15.0.0'
```

add

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
```